Will Pikmin gathered by the other captain be left behind?
In Pikmin 2, you have two separate captains that can control their own group of Pikmin. If I'm playing as Olimar at the end of a day, will the Pikmin being controlled by Louie be left behind? IE: Do I need to consolidate all my Pikmin into a single group at the end of a day?

According to the wiki, Pikmin will be safe at sunset if they are close to the onion, an (in)activated onion or either of the leader's parties.
You can gather Pikmin as Olimar, switch to Louie during the countdown and the Pikmin with Olimar will be safe.
